# Restrict number of GPUs for AMD OpenCL

Tags: opencl

Is there a solution to restrict the used number of GPUs for AMD OpenCL platforms? For NVIDIA platforms one can simply set the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to limit the set of GPUs available to OpenCL.

EDIT: I know, that I can create a context with a reduced set of devices. However, I am looking for ways to control the number of devices *for* the OpenCL platform from "outside".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AMD have the GPU_DEVICE_ORDINAL environment variable for both Windows and Linux. This allows you to specify the indices of the GPUs that you want to be visible from your OpenCL application. For example:

```
jprice@nowai:~/benchmark$ python benchmark.py -clinfo

Platform 0: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
 -> Device 0: Tahiti
 -> Device 1: Tahiti
 -> Device 2: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3550 CPU @ 3.30GHz

jprice@nowai:~/benchmark$ export GPU_DEVICE_ORDINAL=0
jprice@nowai:~/benchmark$ python benchmark.py -clinfo

Platform 0: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
 -> Device 0: Tahiti
 -> Device 1: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3550 CPU @ 3.30GHz
```

A more detailed description can be found in the AMD APP OpenCL Programming Guide (currently in section 2.4.3 "Masking Visible Devices"):
http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/07/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide-rev-2.7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL host  APIs  allow you to specify the the the number of devices  when you get the device ids  list

```
_int clGetDeviceIDs(    
    cl_platform_id platform,
    cl_device_type device_type,
    cl_uint num_entries,  //  Controls the minimum  number of devices
    cl_device_id *devices,
    cl_uint *num_devices)
```

The device id pointer *devices can be used to create the context with a specific number of devices.

Here is what the spec says

> num_entries is the number of cl_device entries that can be added to
>   devices. If devices is not NULL, the num_entries must be greater than
>   zero. devices returns a list of OpenCL devices found. The cl_device_id
>   values returned in devices can be used to identify a specific OpenCL
>   device. If devices argument is NULL, this argument is ignored. The
>   number of OpenCL devices returned is the minimum of the value
>   specified by num_entries or the number of OpenCL devices whose type
>   matches device_type. num_devices returns the number of OpenCL devices
>   available that match device_type. If num_devices is NULL, this
>   argument is ignored

```
cl_context clCreateContext(     
    const cl_context_properties *properties,
    cl_uint num_devices,   // Number of devices 
    const cl_device_id *devices,
    (voidCL_CALLBACK  *pfn_notify) (
        const char *errinfo, 
        const void *private_info, size_t cb, 
        void *user_data
    ),
    void *user_data,
    cl_int *errcode_ret)
```

Each device is then addressed through its own device queue.

Comment: I know all of this. Maybe I wasn't entirely clear, but I was looking for a way to control the devices from "outside". Similar to the environment variable provided by the NVIDIA CUDA driver.

Comment: OK, great! Then invent your own environment variable or use the CUDA one  and call GetEnv().  You should know how to do the rest ....

Answer (score -1):

There is not a portable solution defined by the OpenCL specification.

NVIDIA has the solution you mentioned. I don't think AMD has a standard; your OpenCL programs will have to come up with a way to share the available devices.

Note that AMD does have OpenCL extensions (some of which have become more official in OpenCL 1.2) for "device fission" which is used for splitting up a single device among multiple programs (but that is different than what you are asking).

Comment: I am aware that the OpenCL specification does not provide a mechanism for that (except for restricting the devices in a context). But I will accept your answer as "there is no such thing".

Comment: As jprice described, it can actually be done using a system-variable